# NestJS(TypeORM)でsyncronizeされてしまう

Tags: postgresql, typescript

こんにちは。TypeORMを使用してNestJSで開発してます。
DB接続～開発まで問題なく繋がってはいるのですが。

この度、table(Entity)の即時反映を止め、Migrationで変更を管理しようとしています。本家ページを見るとsynchronize:trueに設定しているとEntityが変わったらBindingされDBにも即時適用されるとの事でこちらをfalseにしてみました。

ただ、それでも起動時の「nest start」でもコンソールのログを見る限りテーブルがCreateされます。シンクロナイズさせない為に他に設定があるのでしょうか？

migrationsRun、autoLoadEntites、下記cliをコメントアウトなど関連しそうなPropertyがあったので全て明示的にfalseを指定してみたのですが、起動時も生成されますし、Entityをいじっても即時反映されてしまいます。

お分かりになる方ございましたら宜しくお願い致します。
また、Entityでcascade指定など、連動してしまう設定値を利用している等の情報もありましたら、宜しくお願い致します。

**ormconfig.js**

```
module.exports = [
 {
  name: 'default',
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  ...
  migrationsRun: false,
  autoLoadEntites: false,
 },
 {
  name: 'migration',
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  ...
  migrationsRun: false,
  autoLoadEntites: false,
  synchronize: false,
　seeds: ['src/db/dml/*.ts'],
　migrations: ['src/db/ddl/*.ts'],
  cli {
    entitiesDir: 'src/domain/entity',
    migrationDir: 'src/db/migration'
  }
 }
]
```

-watch
でテーブルが作成されてしまいます。